# Wordpress 'orderby' => 'post__in' not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to make a custom query by combining two separate queries together, one being all posts with the category of `blog-hub-page` and the other being all remaining posts. The goal with combining these two queries is to have the `blog-hub-page` posts shown first so we can always have hand picked posts up front.

I have done something very similar in the past with a custom post type and the code I have worked perfectly. For some reason when i try to do this with default posts it breaks. Because this seems to be such a straight forward task I feel like I must be missing something simple here. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
        $blogHomeLoop = get_posts( 
            array( 
                'post_type' => 'post', 
                'fields' => 'ids',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'blog_post_loc',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'blog-hub-page'
                    )
                ),
            ) 
        ); 
        $remainingPostLoop = get_posts(
            array(
                'post_type' => 'post', 
                'fields' => 'ids',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'blog_post_loc',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'blog-hub-page',
                        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                    )
                ),
            )
        );
        $mergedLoops = array_merge($blogHomeLoop, $remainingPostLoop);
        remove_all_actions( 'pre_get_posts' );
        wp_reset_query();
        $blogLoop = new WP_Query( 
            array( 
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post__in' => $mergedLoops,
                'orderby' => 'post__in',
                'posts_per_page' => 9,
                'paged' => $paged,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'suppress_filters' => true
            ) 
        );
```

Also here is the SQL from the query object without orderby set

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.ID IN (A LOT OF POST IDS HERE) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 9
```

Here is the same but with orderby set to post__in

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 
AND wp_posts.ID IN (A LOT OF POST IDS HERE) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
ORDER BY FIELD(wp_posts.ID,A LOT OF POST IDS HERE AGAIN) 
LIMIT 0, 9
```

The oddest thing is if I remove `'orderby' => 'post__in'` then it works like a default query. I've even confirmed that it is indeed two merged queries because I made another category and limited the second query to just that category.

So currently it does grab all posts from the two merged queries, and I can tell it to order based on `ASC` or `DESC` which is nice, but as soon as I tell it to order by `'post__in'` then it acts as though there are no posts at all.

If I `print_r($blogLoop->posts);` without `orderby` added then it shows posts as expected. If I add back in `orderby` then it says there are zero posts. Even though i'm able to `print_r($mergedLoops);` and it shows all the IDs as expected.

[Another question had a similar issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/220089/181964) I saw and their suggestion was to add `remove_all_actions('pre_get_posts');`, `wp_reset_query();`, and/or `'suppress_filters' => true` to make sure its not something with those but that solution didn't change anything for me.

Comment: What is being passed to `post__in`? Is it just IDs? Or is there a wrapping `array` around them? Wondering if the `orderby` isn't getting the values it wants. You can get rid of those other suggestions unless you have a `pre_get_posts` somewhere. And you would reset the query AFTER your new query runs.

Comment: Yeah so its just IDs. The first two `get_posts` queries look for the posts in the taxonomy i set and only grab the IDs. Here is a concatenated version of the `$mergedLoops` array when i print it out. This would be what is being passed to `post__in`

`Array ( [0] => 33994 [1] => 33983 [2] => 34269 [3] => 34231 [4] => 33999 [5] => 34216 [2213] => 807 [2214] => 841 [2215] => 496 [2216] => 822 [2217] => 844 )`

Comment: I wonder if the array keys are doing something. Your array looks fine. Try wrapping the `$mergedLoops` in`array_values( $mergedLoops )` That will reset the index keys.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't fix it either. Sucks cause i got excited seeing a new idea i hadn't tried before. It's just so odd, i don't get how if i don't set `orderby` and i print out the posts of the loop it gives me all the posts, but as soon as i tell it to just order the posts then it acts as though it somehow doesn't have them anymore.

Comment: That's weird. The only thing I can think of to fix this is to run two `WP_Query()` - which is what you're probably trying to avoid.

Comment: Yeah and i already tried that as well as a test and it has the same issue. I actually just ran into another interesting part that may help narrow it down. If i remove `'operator' => 'NOT IN'` from the second query then the `'post__in'` works. I double checked this by using a second term in that same taxonomy to combine those two queries and it worked. So now i think it must be something with that query specifically that is causing it to break.

Comment: So after a bit more testing i dont think it actually has anything to do with the operator. It's definitely an issue with my second query, im just not certain what the issue is exactly. If i grab the args for that query and put it directly into my wp_query then it works fine. It grabs all the posts and displays them. But if simply grab the same args with get_posts and set that as an array, like im doing above, and pass that array into my wp_query it does not work. Now, if i limit the amount of posts im grabbing to 1200 it works with get_posts and merging the two arrays and passing to wp_query.

Comment: Hmmm...I would strongly consider using two `WP_Query()` instead. Do one for the posts that have the term and then one that doesn't. Just output them separately.

Comment: Bummer, i just ran through a bunch of tests using wp_query for everything and it still doesn't work. Same overall issue of just it not working when using -1 to get all posts. If i grab a specific number of 1340 (after trial and error) then it works fine in every scenario. I guess for now this is my solution cause most people wont dig that deep for articles anyway but id love to figure it out just for my own sanity some time lol. I really appreciate you helping talk it out with me @disinfor

Comment: No problem! I'm glad you have some sort of work around.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at your code. Did you make a custom taxonomy? If it is default 'taxonomy' => 'blog_post_loc', should be 'taxonomy' => 'category',

Comment: I did make a custom taxonomy called `blog_post_loc`. The reason was because i wanted to use the default category taxonomy for actual tags to be shown on the front end and then i wanted a separate way to do some internal tagging so i could query for those internal tags later.